# Adding a global function

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add a new global function

I am doing it like that:

> Function MessageYNC() As String
>
> {
>        return "dd";
>   }
>
> End Function
>
> Public Class SatelliteAPI
>
> End Class

But i am getting error  ->  Statement is not valid in a namespace.
on the first line

Any idea what is wrong ?

Comment: { return "dd"; } ... that's not VB.NET syntax.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

- The function belongs inside
  the class.
- The curly
  braces and semicolons don't belong
  in VB.  Those are C#.
- In
  order for your method to be global,
  you will need to declare it as
  Shared.  If your entire class
  consists of nothing but shared
  methods, you may consider creating a
  module as opposed to a class. 
  [Here's an explanation of the
  difference between a class with
  shared methods and a module.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net)

---

```
Public Class SatelliteAPI
Public Shared Function MessageYNC() As String
        Return "dd"
    End Function
End Class 'SatelliteAPI

Public Class TestClass
    Public Sub TestMessageMethod()
        Console.WriteLine(SatelliteAPI.MessageYNC)
    End Sub
End Class 'TestClass
```

Comment: Wow.  Stackoverflow destroyed my code sample.  Completely removed line breaks.

Comment: Fixed by adding horizontal rule between list and code sample.  Weird.

Answer (score 2):

Put the function into a class or module. If you put it into a class, you need to make it `Shared`. So it's either

```
Module MyFunctions
    Function MessageYNC() As String
        Return "dd"
    End Function
End Module
```

or

```
Public Class SatelliteAPI
    Shared Function MessageYNC() As String
        Return "dd"
    End Function
End Class
```

in which case you would access it as `StaelliteAPI.MessageYNC`.