# Class vs. Module in VB

Tags: vb.net, class, module

What advantage is there, if any, to using Modules rather than classes in VB? How do they differ, and what advantages/disadvantages are there in using modules? In VB or VB.NET, I use both.

Comment: See this duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net

Comment: It didn't answer my question. I did see it though, thanks.

Comment: What's left of your question after reading that? Please be more specific, as your question sounds very much like that one.

Comment: I also created Module and Class having the same output. It's okay to use class than module, it depends upon the tastes of every programmer. If you want to know my basic sample code, you can visit my site. Just click [here](http://www.tesear.com/2011/09/create-module-and-class-in-vbnet.html)! Hopefully, you appreciate it! Thanks.. I want to share this. If you like, comment me and also share what you have done about vb.net..Thanks again!

Comment: Look at the following playlist on YouTube it explains classes and objects. http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL3FEE93A664B3B2E7&feature=plcp

Answer (score 7, accepted):

(A) *Modules*

and

(B) *Classes with only `Shared` functions*

solve the same problem: Both allow you to logically *group* a set of functions.

Advantages of using a module:

- It allows you to define [extension methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384936.aspx).
- For someone reading your code, it is immediately obvious that this is not a class representing a group of stateful objects but just a "function container".

Advantages of using a class with shared functions:

- It's easy to extend it with *instance* (= non-shared) variables, functions and properties later on.

So, if you are writing a set of helper functions and want to logically group them (where the concept of a *state* of this group just doesn't make sense), use a module -- this is exactly what they are here for. On the other hand, if you have a function that conceptually fits to an already existing class, add it as a shared function to that class.

Answer (score 1):

A major difference is that methods in modules can be called globally whereas methods in classes can't. So instead of `ModuleName.MyMethod()` you can just call `MyMethod()`. Whether that is an advantage or disadvantage depends on the circumstances.

Comment: You can avoid having to type `ClassName.SharedMethodName` by using `Imports ClassName` then you can just type `SharedMethodName`

Answer (score 0):

Module are come earlier and now VB.NET just let it for backward compatibility. Modules and Class are nearly same. You can call Module.Function() directly as it treat as `Shared` Function in a class. Class you can define `Shared` Function/Method and additionally can create an instance like `Dim c as Class = New Class()`.

Avoid use of Module, instead use Class. it is good for you to write a better OOP programming.