# Calling a shared procedure from a module

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, module, master-pages

I would love to use the following procedure to set the Title, keywords etc. of my pages, in a module.

```
  Public Shared Sub SetTitle(ByVal Heading As String, ByVal Keywords As String())
        Dim myMaster As Masterpage = DirectCast(Me.Master, Masterpage)
        If Request.QueryString("lng") = "es" Then
            myMaster.MasterHeading = Heading
            myMaster.MetaTitle = Heading
            myMaster.MetaDescription = ""
            myMaster.MetaKeywords = GetKeywords(Keywords)
        End If
        myMaster.MetaTitle = myMaster.MasterHeading
    End Sub
```

The problem is that i get two errors.

At `Me.Master` i get the `'Me' is valid only within an instance method.` error and at

`If Request...` i get the error

`Cannot refer to an instance member of a class from within a shared method or shared member initializer without an explicit instance of the class.`

So how do i fix these? I would like to have that procedure in a common place and not in every page.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you move this function to a module then you do not need the `shared` keyword as functions in a module are effectively shared. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2646335/class-vs-module-in-vb).