# C# global module

Tags: c#, module

I'm new to c# and I was wondering if someone could tell me how to create a global module for changing a form like you would do in vb, and then how to call that module.

Thanks

Update:

Ok so i have multiple forms and instead of writing the same 2 lines over and over, which are..

```
Form x = new Form1();
x.Show();
```

Is it possible to add this to a class to make it easier. How do i do it? never made a class before. got the class up but unsure how to write the code.

Comment: C# doesn't have modules. Use classes.

Comment: classes with static members are pretty darn close to global modules. namespace.classname.staticmethod( args );

Comment: ok thanks for the class advice. how would i write "form.show" that would apply to all forms in the class... if u understand

Comment: ""form.show" that would apply to all forms in the class"...Ummm please explain what u mean by this.. do you want to open all forms at once... Please clarify..

Comment: no just when i click a button the class gets called and opens the form that corresponds with that button

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is nothing as Global Module in C# instead you can create a Public class with Static Members like:

### Example:

```
//In a class file 

namespace Global.Functions //Or whatever you call it
{
  public class Numbers
  {
    private Numbers() {} // Private ctor for class with all static methods.

    public static int MyFunction()
    {
      return 22;
    }
  }
}

//Use it in Other class 
using Global.Functions
int Age = Numbers.MyFunction();
```

Answer (score 2):

No, this requires help from a compiler.  A VB.NET module gets translated to a class under the hood.  Which is very similar to a static class in C#, another construct that doesn't have a real representation in the CLR.  Only a compiler could then pretend that the members of such a class belong in the global namespace.  This is otherwise a compat feature of the VB.NET compiler, modules were a big deal in the early versions of visual basic.

A static class declared without a namespace is the closest you'll get in C#.  Util.Foo(), something like that.

Answer (score 0):

The answer with `public class` using `static MethodName` is close.  You could take it a step further and make the class static too.

Here is another Stack Overflow answer that talks about it. [Classes vs. Modules in VB.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net/881586#881586)