# How do you access a global variable in C# like In VB.net?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, static

If we declare a `global` variable in module in vb.net, we can use that variable in anywhere in project.

How can we achieve same thing in C#.

Previously when we tried to convert a vb.net project to C#, we succeeded in removing the syntax error but we can't access global variable in a form.

I need some solution or guidance. Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: I think you are looking for something similar
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4751013/c-global-module

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In C# you can declare a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) field.

```
public class Foo
{
   public static string value;
}
```

and use `value` field using ClassName.Member syntax anywhere.

```
Foo.value="Hello!";
```

Comment: Need to mark class `static` as well to use the example provided.

Comment: @Dmitry: no need to set the class `static` since one of his members is `static` field

Comment: @DmitryErokhin: You actually don't need to do that - but making the class static matches more closely what the VB.NET compiler does when you define a Module.

Answer (score 3):

You can approximate a VB.Net `Module` functionality by putting the variable inside of a static class:

```
public static class Foo
{
     public static string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

This will let you access it anywhere in the namespace via `Foo.Bar`.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to also consider using the [Singleton Pattern](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx). This keeps your variable initialization logic in a sensible place. Its also pretty easy to protect or keep track of changes to your variable.

Answer (score 1):

You have to declare them as `static`

[C# Global Variable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable)

[global variables in c#.net - Stack Oveflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445436/global-variables-in-c-net)

Comment: No just your variables that you need to access globally

Comment: but i want to access controls used in that forms globally... pls suggest

Answer (score 0):

Should work the same. Make sure if is marked static. Or try using a static property in your module instead of a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot declare public variable if it's value type such as int,string and etc.

But you can wrap it in struct for example