# convert VB.net Module to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net, module, oracle10g, connection-string

I decided to try out C# for the first time after using VB.net.

Out of curiousity, when I used VB.net I had :

```
Dim conn As OleDbConnection = New OleDbConnection("Provider=""****"";user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd)
```

When trying to convert this format to C# I did the following:

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=****;user id=" & strUserID & ";data source=" & strDatabase & ";password=" & strPssWd
```

However, my strUserId, strDatabase and strPssWd where saved in my Module.vb for VB.net like so:

```
Module Module1
  Friend strDatabase As String = "****"
  Friend strUserID As String = "****"
  Friend strPssWd As String = "****"

End Module
```

How do I make the Module in C# (an example would be helpful) Thanks!

**FYI: I was told [C# Equivalent for VB 'module'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870487/c-sharp-equivalent-for-vb-module) was a duplicate.**

**However the formatting and process of their post isn't equivalent to mine. I am asking a module based on database connection.**

Comment: Duplicated here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30870487/c-sharp-equivalent-for-vb-module

Comment: @Fruitbat I looked at your duplicate link and it doesn't look like what I have. May be asking the same question but results are not what I need. Sstan's answer was what I need based on my format. So if you downgraded my post then I don't know why.

Comment: Not me. I just put the link there because I thought it was what you needed.

Comment: @Fruitbat I see. I just got a "duplicate" alert at top with same link so that is why I asked. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put constants in a `public static class` like this:

```
public static class MyConnectionStringConstants
{
    public const string strDatabase = "****";
    public const string strUserID = "****";
    public const string strPssWd = "****";
}
```

To use it, you will need to refer to the constants like this:

```
string strAccessConn = "Provider=****;user id=" + MyConnectionStringConstants.strUserID + ";data source=" + MyConnectionStringConstants.strDatabase + ";password=" + MyConnectionStringConstants.strPssWd
```

BTW, in C#, you concatenate strings using the `+` operator, not the `&` operator.

Comment: Thank you for clarification and example. The format of what you sent is exactly similar to my old version. I really appreciate it! I also wasn't fully aware yet that c# uses + so appreciate that information.