# What does the keyword 'Shared' mean in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, types, shared

Is `Shared` is a type of scope or a type of data in VB.NET?  When is it necessary to use the `Shared` word before a class, function, or sub in VB.NET?  For instance, why would you put `Shared` in front of the `Main` method, like this:

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    ' ...
End Sub
```

Comment: I ussually avoid using the `shared` keyword before entire classes, instead I declare it as a module.[This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net) goes much farther into it if you are curious. But I think it breaks down to personal preference.

Answer (score 3):

The `Shared` modifier in VB.NET is the same as the `static` modifier in C#.  It's neither scope (because it can be `Private` or `Public`) nor a data type.  According to the [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx):

> Specifies that one or more declared programming elements are associated with a class or structure at large, and not with a specific instance of the class or structure.

Answer (score 2):

Shared Main does not make sense (if you build a console application)

Here is an example for shared:

```
Class WithShared
  Shared Sub A_Method()
  End Sub
End Class

Class WithoutShared
  Sub A_Method()
  End Sub
End Class
```

now possible code in your Main:

```
Dim WithSharedInstance as New WithShared()
WithSharedInstance.A_Method() 'does not work
WithShared.A_Method() 'works

Dim WithoutSharedInstance as New WithShared()
WithoutSharedInstance.A_Method() 'works
WithoutShared.A_Method() 'does not work
```

So if a call does not depend on a specific instance, then use Shared. Since you call Shared Methods through the classdefinition, you cannot access variables and methods, which only exist when the class is instanced.

Comment: Dim WithoutSharedInstance as New WithShared() should be changed to Dim WithoutSharedInstance as New WithoutShared().

Answer (score 1):

For functions and subs, it means that the function or sub belongs to the class itself, not to an instance of the class. For example, `String.IsNullOrEmpty` refers to a shared method, whereas `myString.TrimEnd()` refers to an instance (non-shared) method.

In C# you can make a class static, which means that all of the members will be static. This is not supported in VB (at least not according to [this documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). Modules in VB serve a very similar purpose to static classes in C#.

The only time I can think of when a method *needs* to be static (shared) is when another static member references it. Otherwise, they're very useful for certain scenarios, such as when a particular method or property doesn't need to retain or access any instance-specific state, but they're not usually necessary.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to look at this is by example:

```
Dim firstName as String = "Bob"
Dim lastName as String = "Jones"
Dim fullName as String = String.Format("{0} {1}", firstName, lastName.ToUpper())
```

If you were creating the String.ToUpper() and String.Format() functions you need to differentiate between a function that acts on an instance of a class and one which doesn't.

If you were writing a class like `String`:

`.Format()` would be declared Shared, because it doesn't need an object.
`.ToUpper()` wouldn't because it needs an object instance. The value it returns is related to the object.