# What is the replacement for Shared variables on Modules on VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, module, shared

Does it even exist? I want to have a shared variable across a module and a class that belong to the same project.

Comment: Declare a variable as Shared. This means it's shared between all instances of the class. [Link to MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zc2b427x.aspx).

Comment: @Neolisk You cannot declare shared variables in a Module though.

Comment: No, don't use modules. These are something from the old VB6 world. Make a habit to always use classes. If they will contain all shared methods and shared variables - so be it.

Comment: Yeah it wasn't my choice though, and there's not much I can do to avoid it.

Comment: @Neolisk I disagree. [Modules are not deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/a/881586/1603095)

Comment: @NePh: Modules have its use, like extension methods, but most new VB.NET developers tend to use them as global bucket for random stuff. They are not scoped and introduce clutter when misused. Tried to advocate against that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Shared` variables exist but you probably mean the old fashioned `Global` variables.  For that, just declare a variable in an actual module rather than a Class:

```
Friend Foo As Integer
Public Bar As String = ""
```

Static vars are quite different

Comment: While I'm not exactly sure why, just declaring public variables in the Module did actually let me use them in the other classes. Interesting.

Comment: 'Friend' will allow the same scope, while 'Public' will make the variables visible outside the assembly.

Comment: Why does it work different from a class though? If I just declare public variables on Class1 I can't see them on Class2 unless I instantiate.

Comment: **All** class variables require the class to be instanced - thats just how classes work (unless the member is `Shared`).  Public vs Friend for them just means whether things outside the class can reference them.  For something like the old `Global` variable, you need a Friend or Public variable in a module as in the answer.  Usually you can avoid these by using a simple Class as a container, but yes, then that means you need to use them as `If myClass.myVar = "Foo"...`

Answer (score 0):

you can look into static variables. that's probably the closest thing to shared variables.