# How to structure a vb.net program

Tags: vb.net

I have a basic question trying to understand the correct way to structure a vb.net solution.

So, suppose I'd like to create a database application for a supermarket.
How would I go seperating the different code modules, the appropriate classes, the modules etc.
Should I create a single file with all my clases, a single module with all my public shared methods, should I create a single namespace to include everything or should I seperate each class in its own physical file (one class per vb file), seperate modules according to usage etc.
What I want to know is how should one think when having to organize the different code units when designing a solution in vb.net.

BR

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net?rq=1 this might help

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that the possible answers to your question are suitable for the scope & focus of stackoverflow. **However**, I think that you can find several approaches & guidelines for structuring a vb.net solution in the following links:

- [MSDN guidelines for "Structuring Solutions and Projects"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817674.aspx).
- This very helpful [article regarding ".net Naming Conventions and Programming Standards"](http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices).
- [A youTube video called "How to structure a .net project"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KM5o9M4cuQA) which addresses some of the elements of your question.

It's probably not **all** there is to say (or know), but it's a good start.

Comment: Great but still I cant create a logical structure I  my mind.

Comment: Lets start with classes. 1 per file or multiple in 1 file? Namespaces. Should i try seperating logical units in different namespaces or go for less namespaces with more generic description and seperate logic with different class names? Assembies. Does one assembly include all dll files? Are each dll file = each seperate class, so if I have 10 classes I get 10 dll files? Are each one of them a seperate physical file on my hd? Modules. Should I include class definitions in modules, or only public shared methods.