# How do VB.NET static classes work?

Tags: vb.net, module, static-class

I understood them to be modules, such as my little one:

```
Public Module Config
    Public Property ImportSettings As ImportConfig
    Sub New()
        ImportSettings = ImportConfig.Read()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Yet, I cannot access `ImportSettings`. I'm told it's not declared, and its value is 'Nothing'.

Comment: You cannot initialize a module. It cannot be used as a type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Classes vs. Modules in VB.Net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net) | And here's a bonus link: [google.com?q=vb.net module statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aaxss7da.aspx).

Comment: @OneFineDay - not quite true. You can have a "static constructor" in a module

Answer (score 0):

Static(C#)/Shared(VB) method/property in a class:

```
Public Class Config
  Public Shared ReadOnly Property ImportSettings As ImportConfig
    Get
       Return ImportConfig.Read()
    End Get
  End Property
End Class
```

Usage:

```
Dim configs = Config.ImportSettings
```

Since it is Static/Shared we do not need to initialize the Config class.