# Raising an event in .net example

Tags: .net, vb.net, events, event-handling

I am trying to create a basic example of raising an event in vb.net, and I am hoping that by studying it thoroughly I can upgrade the way my system receives data from serial port.

Right now I have a system that receives the incoming data from serial port via timers, the problem is there are certain events in a system that conflicts in my timer. Because of this I am planning to change the way I received the data from serial ports, instead of timer I want to use vb.net raiseevent.

Unfortunately I can't find a simple example on how to use this event, by searching thoroughly I saw the **MSDN's** post about this topic and [it is here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h7a2kh64(VS.80).aspx). So, how do I use this example? I tried using it below like that

```
Public Event TimeExpired(ByVal Status As String)
Public Sub RaiseTimeExpiredEvent()
    RaiseEvent TimeExpired("Your time has run out")
    MessageBox.Show(TimeExpired())
End Sub
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseTimeExpiredEvent()
End Sub
```

It's not working working, the error is

> Error 1   'Public Event TimeExpired(Status As String)' is an event, and cannot be called directly. Use a 'RaiseEvent' statement to raise an event.    C:\Users\Cary\Desktop\Projects\Testing\Testing\Testing\Form1.vb 5   25  Testing

Because of that error I tried to do it like this

```
Class Form1
Public Event TimeExpired(ByVal Status As String)
Public Sub RaiseTimeExpiredEvent()
    RaiseEvent TimeExpired("Your time has run out")
    MessageBox.Show(TimeExpired())

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    RaiseEvent TimeExpired()
End Sub
```

End Class

But the error states

> Error 2   Argument not specified for parameter 'Status' of 'Public Event TimeExpired(Status As String)'.  C:\Users\Cary\Desktop\Projects\Testing\Testing\Testing\Form1.vb 11  9   Testing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Are you using Visual Studio ? If yes, you can try to display the Error List. For that, click View, and Error List.

```
Class Form1

    Public Event TimeExpired(Status As String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent TimeExpired("Your time has run out")
    End Sub

End Class
```

**To handle the event, you can add this :**

```
Private Sub HandleTimeExpired(Status As String) Handles Me.TimeExpired
    MsgBox(Status)
End Sub
```

**Here is the full code :**

```
Class Form1

    Public Event TimeExpired(Status As String)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        RaiseEvent TimeExpired("Your time has run out")
    End Sub

    Public Sub OnTimeExpired(Status As String) Handles Me.TimeExpired
        MsgBox(Status)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**Edit :**

If you wanna move the raising of event in a module, you can't. You have to add it in a class. [See this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net).

**Example of Class1 (you should rename it...) :**

```
Public Class Class1

    Private Event TimeExpired(Status As String)

    Public Sub OnTimeExpired(Status As String)
        RaiseEvent TimeExpired(Status)
    End Sub

    Private Sub HandleTimeExpired(Status As String) Handles Me.TimeExpired
       MsgBox(Status)
    End Sub

End Class
```

**And to use it, you have to declare it WithEvents in your Form1 :**

```
Public Class Form1

    Dim WithEvents Class1 As New Class1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Class1.OnTimeExpired("Your time has run out")
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Yes I'm using VS 2013. Well, I'm just learning vb.net. Nothing happens when I clicked the button, I even tried replacing `msgbox` with `console.writeline`

Comment: @OneFineDay I think your answer is too hard for him, he's learning... ;)

Comment: Your answer seems to be so easy to understand for me. This is great and better!

Comment: I just think that the OneFineDay's Foo class is useless...
According to me, my answer is better, but choose what you prefer! ;)

Comment: You're using the `On*` convention wrongly. Methods like `OnTimeExpired` should **raise** the event and not **handle** the event. The handler should also probably be `Private` and not `Public`.

Comment: @Enigmativity  you mean the declaration of `OnTimeExpired`? So by making it `HandleTimeExpired` it will become valid?

Comment: @Drarig29, one more thing if it is okay. I am trying to move the raising of event in a module, unfortunately it states `handles in modules must specify a 'withevents' variable`, I tried to do that but another `error` occurs. :(

Comment: @CaryBondoc - Yes. The `On*` methods are usually `protected` methods to enable descendent classes to be able to raise the event.

Comment: @Drarig29, exellent answer and example. Thanks!