# Accessing a shared module from anywhere

Tags: vb.net

I have converted a C# source to VB containing a `class` `Logger` and a `static class` containing instances of `Logger`.

But using VB.NET, I can't figure out how to create a `Module` I can access from other source files in the same namespace.

I would simply like to access the object like I would do in C#:

```
Loggers.MyLogger.MyMethod()
```

or

```
MyNamespace.Loggers.MyLogger.MyMethod()
```

But that only works from the same file !

```
Public Shared Module Loggers
    Public Shared ReadOnly MyLogger As Logger = New Logger()
End Module

Public Class Logger
..class content...
End Class
```

EDIT: Since I also tried with "shared", I guess something is wrong on the project level.

Comment: Loggers.MyLogger

Comment: This does not work from another file.

Comment: what's the fully qualified namespace in VS for the project...use that namespace and append .Loggers.MyLogger

Comment: I should have mentionned I also tried this.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you managed to miss this or fool the compiler, but on my Visual Studio, I get an error when I try to make a shared module. Modules are implicitly shared, and you're not allowed to apply the `Shared` keyword explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

A `Module` can't be declared explicitly as `Shared`, because it implicitly is `Shared`.

Change your code like following and it should work:

```
Public Module Loggers
    Public ReadOnly MyLogger As Logger = New Logger()
End Module

Public Class Logger
    Public Sub MyMethod()

    End Sub
End Class
```

References:

- [Shared](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/shared)
- [Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement)
- [Classes vs. Modules in VB.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/881570/classes-vs-modules-in-vb-net)

Comment: Already tried also. I have added Shared because this was not working.

Comment: Above code works. Create a new project and try it. How did you declare `MyMethod`?

Comment: I guess something is wrong at project level then.The method I am trying to call is

    Public Sub Information(ByVal message As String, ByVal Optional context As String = Nothing)
        _Message("Info", message, context)
    End Sub

But might be irrelevant. Intelisense does not even find the module.

Comment: @Julien Holopainen Az Declare that `Class Logger` methods as `Shared`. Not the Class or the Module.